# R - Delete days with less than 24 measurements (delete rows if number of rows with date < 24)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of the date and the air temperature of each hour like this:

```
date    t.air
1   2013-05-01  11.1
2   2013-05-01  10.3
3   2013-05-01  9.5
4   2013-05-01  9.0
5   2013-05-01  8.6
6   2013-05-01  8.0
```

I should have 24 rows of 2013-05-01, t.air and then 24 rows of the next day and so on. 
For computing the daily minimum and maximum temperature, I want to only consider days with 24 measurements.

How can I program something like
"If there are less than 24 values of "day", delete all rows with "day""?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`.  If `dat` is the dataset

```
  library(data.table)
  setDT(dat)[,.SD[.N>=24], by=date]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
subset(dat, ave(date, date, FUN = length) >= 24)
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Comment: I get the error: 
Error in as.Date.numeric(x) : 'origin' must be supplied